# Questions with Custom Objects

Tags: vb.net, class, object

If I have 2 custom datatypes/Classes let's say for example: Class A & Class B

If I do this in CLASS C

```
Public Class C
Public Property F As New Object
End Class
```

Can I actually i Assign Class A or Class B to the F property and be able to use/assigns its properties & methods through class C?

I've tried assigning Class A or Class B to my F object, but it errors. Is there a way to actually accomplish this?

Thank you!

Edit form what I understood reading into DirectCast:

In my Sub (when I already know what object to cast to):

```
    Dim myClassCObject As New Class C
    dim x as string = "Some String"
    myClassCObject.TypeFind(x)
    If myClassCObject.GetType.ToString = "ClassA" then
        Assign ClassA Properties
     Elseif MyClassOBject.GetType.ToString = "ClassB" then
     'Assign ClassB properties
    End if
```

How About the following Within the Class C Class:

```
 Public Sub TypeFind(X as string)
    'x.count will let me know what type i need to cast to.
    If X.Count = 16 then
    F = DirectCast(F, ClassA)
    Else
    F = DirectCast(F, ClassB)
    End if
    End Sub
```

^^^^^
'Unforuntaley this causes a run-timeerror and does not work

What I am asking in more detail:

When I instantiate a Class C object, I want to be able to Assign the F property of Class C to be either a ClassA or a ClassB object based on a string parameter I have. Remember that the F property starts as just a plain OBJECT and want to change it to either ClassA or ClassB and then load the respective properties. Hence the non-working method I wrote called TypeFind(x as string). x being the parameter the determines the object to change F to which is a Method of the Class C Class

Comment: Assuming you have option strict on (You Should) You will need to cast the F property to the Correct Type to access the properties of Class A or B.

Comment: `Public Class C(Of T As New) ... Public Property F As T = New T()`. If that's what you mean.

Comment: this seems to not work when I declare a List(Of Class C).  It asks for me to define T,  but T can be either Class A or Class B.  There for a huge public list(of class C) has to be restricted to what you define (OF T) to be.  Or am I missing something

Comment: No that doesn't look right, myClassCObject.F will still be an object do matter what you set it too.  You need to do the type check and change when accessing myClassCObject.F

Comment: im not understanding how =(

Comment: Then you could: 1) Implement an Interface that exposes all the common Properties / Methods needed, ditch the `New` constraint and add a constructor with a parameter to `C` 2) Use a Base class and a widening operator in `C` (e.g., `public shared widening operator CType(vb As C(Of B)) As C(Of T) Return New C(Of T) end operator`), but of course you have to define an operator for each sub-class allowed. 3) Ditch `C` and `New` and use the base class alone. 4) Use just a `List(Of [Base class])` and cast as required. 5) Use a `List(Of Object)` and cast as required.

Comment: Maybe have a read up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/typeof-operator.  From there you can use flow control (If/Case statements) to work with the appropriate type definitions

Comment: It sounds like you should implement an interface on those classes you want to use on that Property.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments, it's not really what happens when you set your property, it's what happens when you retrieve it that you want to handle.  Not the most perfect solution but as a starter, something like this

```
Dim instance1 as New ClassC
Dim instance2 as New ClassC

instance1.F = new ClassA
instance2.F = new ClassB

DoSomeWork(instance1)
DoSomeWork(instance2)

Sub DoSomeWork(ByVal myClassCObject as ClassC)
    If TypeOf myClassCObject.F  Is ClassA Then
        with DirectCast(myClassCObject.F, ClassA)
            'Do ClassA Suff
        End with
    ElseIf TypeOf myClassCObject.F  Is ClassB Then
        with DirectCast(myClassCObject.F, ClassB)
            'Do ClassB Stuff
        End with
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, if there are some shared properties between ClassA and ClassB, you might want to look at inheritance or interfaces which allows you to scope things a little finer than just Object

Comment: Do I put this as a Method/Sub in Class C?

Comment: You would do this type of thing wherever your needing to to know if you're working with a ClassA or ClassB instance.

Comment: So I cannot switch between Class B and Class A of the Property F with every instantiation of Class C in my application?

Comment: Sure you can myClassC_1.F can be of type ClassA and another instance myClassC_2.F can be type ClassB.  Or is what your asking you want to convert ClassA to be ClassB or vice versa at any stage?

Comment: what im asking is... When I instantiate a Class C object,  I want to be able to Assign the F property to be  either ClassA or ClassB based on a string parameter I have.  Remeber that the F property starts as just a plain OBJECT and want to change it to either ClassA or ClassB and then load the respective properties.  Hence the non-working method I wrote called TypeFind(x as string).  x being the parameter the determines the object to change F to which is a Method in the Class C Class.

Comment: I've updated my answer a little, does this explain better?

Comment: you kind of did,  I figured it out though.  Solution Posted.

Answer (score -1):

My Solution to the problem

No need to cast.

In The Class C Object I removed NEW from the F property.

So Now Class C looks like this:

```
Public Class C
Public F As Object
End Class
```

Since there is not a new instance of F when I instanciate my Class C.

I can now call this method within Class C:

```
Public Sub InitializeType(x as string)
if x.count > 10
F = New ClassA
Else
F = New ClassB
End If
End Sub

Public Sub CastType(ByRef myObject as Object)
If typeof F is  ClassA then
myObject = DirectCast(myObject, ClassA)
Else if typeof F is ClassB Then
myObject = DirectCast(myObject, ClassB)
End if
```

In my application and how I fanagled it:

```
    Dim MyClassCObject as New ClassC
    MyClassCObject.InitializeType("xxxxxxxxxxx")
    'String is longer than 10 so F type in ClassC is now a NEW ClassA
dim myObject as obJect
MyClassObject.CastType(myObject)
```

myObject can now use the correct properties I need.

it works for what I want even though I probably did it ALL wrong

Time to throw a party

Comment: Just a not here, this will only work if both ClassA and ClassB have a property called SomeClassAProperty.

Comment: Not really square one.  take what you've got here, then combine with the type checking in my answer for when you want to access the properties of F

Comment: I actually fanagled it a bit to work tho.  Posting Solution

Comment: "Since there is not a new instance of F when I instanciate my Class C." What?

Comment: lol sorry... its a little confusing but It works for what I needed it to do.